# Third rule not being recognized in if statement

Tags: python

I'm new to coding and I've been going through and just doing random challenges online to get the hand of python and coding in general, one of the challenges though has me stumped in a certain spot.

I'm trying to write some code where you simply play Rock, Paper, Scissors with the program, however when ever I choose scissors the program returns nothing even though I have went over the if statements multiple times and everything seems to be correct from what I have seen so far.

Any help on this or even just constructive criticism on my code overall is greatly appreciated, weather it be on how I structure my code or a simple way to do something that I elaborated to much on. Thank you so much!

My Code:

```
import random
import sys
import os
import time

clear = lambda: os.system('cls')

x = 0
y = 0

clear()

uChoice = raw_input("Rock, Paper, or Scissors?")

clear()

poss = ["Rock...", "Paper...", "Scissors..."]

while x < 3:
    print(poss[y])
    time.sleep(2)
    x = x + 1
    y = y + 1

time.sleep(2)

print("SHOOT!")
time.sleep(0.2)

sChoice = random.randrange(1,4)

if sChoice == 1:
    sChoicet = "Rock"
elif sChoice == 2:
    sChoicet = "Paper"
elif sChoice == 3:
    sChoicet = "Scissors"

if uChoice == "Rock" and sChoice == 1 or uChoice == "Paper" and sChoice == 2 or uChoice == "Scissors" and sChoice == "3":
    print("The opponent chose %s" %(sChoicet))
    print("The match was a draw.")
elif uChoice == "Rock" and sChoice == 2 or uChoice == "Paper" and sChoice == 3 or uChoice == "Scissors" and sChoice == "1":
    print("The opponent chose %s" %(sChoicet))
    print("You lost the match, unlucky.")
elif uChoice == "Rock" and sChoice == 3 or uChoice == "Paper" and sChoice == 1 or uChoice == "Scissors" and sChoice == "2":
    print("The opponent chose %s" %(sChoicet))
    print("You won the match!")
```

Comment: Half way through, `sChoice` changes from an int to a string. e.g. `if ... uChoice == "Scissors" and sChoice == "3":`

Comment: `sChoice == "3"` is never going to be true, because `3` != `"3"`.

Comment: use `print()` (and `print(type(...))` ) to check values in variable and which part of code is executed - it helps to see what is happening in code, and to find problem.

Comment: UGH I'm so sorry I looked at it for like 15 minutes and couldn't see it I just get tripped up on the small stuff too often, thank you , and alright Ill try to do that more @furas

Comment: You might also want to wrap those conditions with parenthesis ...

Comment: Another tip: `os.system('cls')` won't work on Unix environments... You can consider changing that to `os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')`

Answer (score 0):

Just change the end of your code as follows:

```
if uChoice == "Rock" and sChoice == 1 or uChoice == "Paper" and sChoice == 2 or uChoice == "Scissors" and sChoice == 3:
    print("The opponent chose %s" %(sChoicet))
    print("The match was a draw.")
elif uChoice == "Rock" and sChoice == 2 or uChoice == "Paper" and sChoice == 3 or uChoice == "Scissors" and sChoice == 1:
    print("The opponent chose %s" %(sChoicet))
    print("You lost the match, unlucky.")
elif uChoice == "Rock" and sChoice == 3 or uChoice == "Paper" and sChoice == 1 or uChoice == "Scissors" and sChoice == 2:
    print("The opponent chose %s" %(sChoicet))
    print("You won the match!")
```

You were comparing a `String` with an `Integer` value, reason why the comparison was never true.